# Simple Schema not working

Tags: javascript, meteor

I keep getting the following error in my meteor.js app i don't know whats wrong been following a tutorial did every exactly:

Here is my code:

```
Recepies = new Mongo.collection('recepies');

RecepieSchema = new SimpleSchema({
 name: {
    type: string,
    label: "Name"
  },
desc: {
    type: string,
    label: "Description"
   },
author: {
    type: string,
    label: "Author",
    autoValue: function () {
        return this.userId
    }
  },
createdAt: {
    type: date,
    label: "created At",
    autoValue: function () {
        return new Date()
     }
   }
  });
  Recepies.attachSchema( RecepieSchema);
```

The error in terminal:

> Started MongoDB.
>   W20160212-14:38:03.572(2)? (STDERR)
>   W20160212-14:38:03.575(2)? (STDERR)/Users/sypher47/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
>   W20160212-14:38:03.575(2)? (STDERR)                         throw(ex);
>   W20160212-14:38:03.575(2)? (STDERR)                               ^
>   W20160212-14:38:03.575(2)? (STDERR) TypeError: undefined is not a function
>   W20160212-14:38:03.575(2)? (STDERR)     at collections/Recepies.js:1:12
>   W20160212-14:38:03.576(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/sypher47/recipes/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/app/collections/Recepies.js:39:4
>   W20160212-14:38:03.576(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/sypher47/recipes/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:242:10
>   W20160212-14:38:03.576(2)? (STDERR)     at Array.forEach (native)
>   W20160212-14:38:03.576(2)? (STDERR)     at Function.*.each.*.forEach (/Users/sypher47/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.10.1b51q9m++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
>   W20160212-14:38:03.576(2)? (STDERR)     at /Users/sypher47/recipes/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/boot.js:137:5
>   => Exited with code: 8

Comment: Have you `meteor add`ed `aldeed:collection2@2.8.0`? Also, please check the [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), your code is not properly formatted.

Comment: yes  i have added collection2 i even had to install aldeed:simple-schema but nothing seems to be working. Sorry about the formatting

Answer (score 3):

You need to define the collection with an uppercase 'C':

`Recepies = new Mongo.Collection('recepies');`

Yours reads `Mongo.collection` so you are getting an `undefined is not a function` error.